# Boost/OpenCV error: no match for call to '(boost::_mfi::dm<void(cv::Mat*, cv::VideoCapture*), Recorder>)

Tags: c++, opencv, boost

I'm want to achieve a "smooth" video recording using OpenCV and the Boost libaries.
For that i'm trying to implement the code I found [here](https://aaka.sh/patel/2013/06/28/live-video-webcam-recording-with-opencv/) in to my program. I'm not too familiar with Boost yet and I keep getting the error **\bind.hpp:313: error: no match for call to '(boost::_mfi::dm) (cv::Mat*&, cv::VideoCapture*&)'
         unwrapper::unwrap(f, 0)(a[base_type::a1_], a[base_type::a2_]);**

My code is the following:

```
#include "recorder.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include "boost/thread.hpp"


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::posix_time;

Recorder::Recorder(){ 

     webcamRecorder.open(1);
     webcamRecorder.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920);
     webcamRecorder.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080);
     recordingCount=0;
     filename = "F:/MyVideo";
     ext=".avi";
     hasStarted=false;  
}

void Recorder::captureFunc(Mat *matRecorder, VideoCapture *webcamRecorder){
      for(;;){
            //capture from webcame to Mat frame
            (*webcamRecorder) >> (*matRecorder);
            resize(*matRecorder,matOut,Size(1280,720),0,0,INTER_LINEAR);
        }
}
void Recorder::setup(){
    if (!hasStarted){
        this->start();
        boost::thread captureThread(&Recorder::captureFunc, &matRecorder, &webcamRecorder);

    }
}
void Recorder::run(){
    cout << "++++++++recorder thread called+++" << endl;

    theVideoWriter.open(filename+countAsString+ext,CV_FOURCC('L','A','G','S'), 30, Size(1280,720), true);

    nextFrameTimestamp = microsec_clock::local_time();
    currentFrameTimestamp = nextFrameTimestamp;
    td = (currentFrameTimestamp - nextFrameTimestamp);    

    if ( theVideoWriter.isOpened() == false ){
        cout << "ERROR: Failed to write the video" << endl;
    }
    if (recording){
        while(recording){
            hasStarted=true;
            while(td.total_microseconds() < 1000000/30){
            //determine current elapsed time
                currentFrameTimestamp = microsec_clock::local_time();
                td = (currentFrameTimestamp - nextFrameTimestamp);
            }

            //       determine time at start of write
            initialLoopTimestamp = microsec_clock::local_time();

            theVideoWriter << matOut; // write video file

            nextFrameTimestamp = nextFrameTimestamp + microsec(1000000/30);
            td = (currentFrameTimestamp - nextFrameTimestamp);

            finalLoopTimestamp = microsec_clock::local_time();
            td1 = (finalLoopTimestamp - initialLoopTimestamp);
            delayFound = td1.total_milliseconds();
            cout << delayFound << endl;

        }
    }
    hasStarted=false;
    cout << "finished recording" << endl;
    theVideoWriter.release();
    recordingCount++;
    countAsString = static_cast<ostringstream*>( &(ostringstream() << recordingCount) )->str();

}
void Recorder::setRecording(bool x){ recording = x;}
```

What is wrong with my implementation? Again the original code pieces are from [here](https://aaka.sh/patel/2013/06/28/live-video-webcam-recording-with-opencv/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, and the difference between your case and the link you provided, is that you use an object method for the thread function. Specifically:

```
boost::thread captureThread(&Recorder::captureFunc, &matRecorder, &webcamRecorder);
```

An object method needs a pointer for `this`. Since you create the thread in an object method, you can use its `this` pointer:

```
boost::thread captureThread(&Recorder::captureFunc, this, &matRecorder, &webcamRecorder);
```

Some general suggestions:

1. You don't need boost for threads anymore. `C++11` has it in its standard library. I suggest you use it if you can.
2. The thread you created becomes `detached` - it continues executing, but you can't control it. You probably want to save it somewhere, so you can `join` it later.

To have the thread as an instance variable:

1. Have the thread declared in the class definition: `std::thread captureThread;`.
2. Have it initialized in the current function, and **moved** to the instance variable:

   std::thread localCaptureThread(&Recorder::captureFunc, this, &matRecorder, &webcamRecorder);
   captureThread = std::move(localCaptureThread);

Comment: thank you, this works! If I wan't to use the c++11 standard library for the thread I would have to change it to **std::thread captureThread(&Recorder::captureFunc, this, &matRecorder, &webcamRecorder);** correct? My program crashes as soon as the thread gets called if I do it this way

Comment: well, I should have noted that the C++11 thread terminates the thread on destruction. If you use it, you should make it an instance variable.

Comment: I'm still new to threads. Isn't it an instance variable already? I get **Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.** twice if I run my code with std::thread. I really would prefere doing it with the standard library.

Comment: the `Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function` is unrelated to the threading issue. This error is usually printed with more information (like the assertions failed). About the variable itself, it's currently a `local` variable. It gets destructed when its scope ends, which is when the containing function reaches its end. You can have an instance variable in your class definition, and then initialize it in the function. IMHO, it's best like in the edit.